# Liferay Exception Handling

Tags: liferay

How to get original exception Object at portlet_error.jsp as it only shows "ABC Portlet Temporarily Unavailble" but i want to print actual Error/Exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This JSP-file is included in `html/portal/render_portlet.jsp`, so you can create a simple [JSP Hook](http://babujanarthanan.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-jsp-hooks-in-liferay.html) that overrides this JSP and display the wanted Exception information.

Comment: When I override this JSP, how can I get my hands on the actual exception object? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what you'd like to do with it. If you want to do specific handling for a certain exception, you can always do an `instanceof` and cast to get to the information you need.